# How do you add custom page entries in Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have a paper written in LaTeX with a LaTeX generated Table of Contents. I need to attach an Appendix that is generated in Word but have the Table of Contents show the entries from the Appendix.

Is there some type of LaTeX command that will allow me to add an entry to the Table of Contents with the page number from the Appendix manually?

Comment: calling `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{test}` right in front of the appendix?

Comment: The appendix is in a separate file which Latex doesn't know anything about, so the pages don't line up.

Comment: if you want `hyperef` support, you should also use `\phantomsection`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not mind throwing away some additional dummy pages at the end of your latex generated document, this might work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \section{main part}

    \lipsum

    \newpage
    \pagestyle{empty} % in case you accidentially print theses pages, they will be empty and the paper can be reused
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{appendix A}
    \mbox{}

    \newpage 
    \setcounter{page}{42}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{appendix B}
    \mbox{}

\end{document}
```